# list all possible combinations of a 9x9 box with 9 cells are occupied each time

Tags: java, algorithm

this is the 2D array 9x9 grids initially

```
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000
```

if a cell is occupied, it will use 1 to represent...
and each time there must be 9 cells to be used at a time...

```
111111111  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000  
000000000
```

how to write some codes to generate all the different combination with these nine "1" in the 9x9 graph?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  I doubt it is really to generate *all* of the combinations.

Comment: You probably are not going to run that code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nested loops are not a good idea for n choose k problems:**
If you had to occupy only 2 cells, you could do that (pseudo-code):

```
for(int i= 0; i < grid.length*grid[0]*length; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < grid.length*grid[0]*length; j++){
        // Build grid with cells i and j occupied
    }
}
```

With 3, you would have to do this:

```
for(int i= 0; i < grid.length*grid[0]*length; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < grid.length*grid[0]*length; j++){
        for(int j = k + 1; k < grid.length*grid[0]*length; k++){
            // Build grid with cells i, j and k occupied
        }
    }
}
```

... I suppose you see the problem now, to have 9 cells occupied, you would have 9 nested loops (nasty), and more importantly, your code won't be valid for any other value of occupied cells.

Use recursion, I'm not doing it for you but here is a clue:

The point of recursion is to reduce the problem so many times that it will become trivial. What's a trivial case here?
n-choose-1 is trivial, it's n.

```
// This function calculates n-choose-k
public static int nchoosek(int n, int k){
    if(k == 1){
        return n;
    }else{
            // To come up with this, you need to write down your equation and try
            // to express n-choose-k as a function of n-1-choose-k-1
        return nchoosek(n - 1, k - 1) * n / k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a recursive method, or a couple of nested for loops.

However, you should know that there are

[81 choose 9 = 260 887 834 350](http://www.google.com/search?q=81+choose+9)

such combinations.

Comment: I really don't think nested loops are a good solution for this, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @nathanb, I'm not saying it's the most elegant solution, but if I where to do 260887834350 iterations, I'd rather do it using for-loops instead of 9 method calls *per cell*.

Comment: If the number of iteration is too big for recursive method and would produce a StackOverflowException, you should use a while-based recursion, in this case: while(k>0){res *= n-- / k--;}

Comment: What are you talking about. The recursion-depth is 9 calls.